# Need tabs to hold their own state, so it can hold its own number of items within

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import StarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Star';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import TwitterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Twitter';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';

class TwitterBot extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTabState = this.handleTabState.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        loaded: [],
        searched: [],
        searchedTicker: '',
        actveTab: '',
        addedTickers: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        //Gathering data from heroku API I built and adding tweets to loaded array state
        let feed = await axios.get('https://boiling-plains-63502.herokuapp.com/');
        let tweets = feed.data;
        this.setState({
            loaded: tweets
        });
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        //Watching input and changing searchedTicker string while typing
        this.setState({ searchedTicker: e.target.value });
    };

    handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
        //Selecting the correct tab
        this.setState({ tabValue: newValue });
    };

    handleTabState = (e, data) => {
        //This is changing searchedTicker state to the value of whichever tab is clicked
        this.setState({ searchedTicker: data });
    };

    showAll = () => {
        //Clearing searched state
        this.setState({ searchedTicker: '' });
    };

    addTicker = () => {
        // Adding ticker to saved list
        if (this.state.searchedTicker.length > 0) {
            this.setState((state) => {
                const tickers = state.addedTickers.push(state.searchedTicker);
                return {
                    tickers,
                    searchedTicker: ''
                };
            });
        } else {
            alert('Plase enter a symbol to search');
        }
    };
    removeTicker = (e, data) => {
        // Removing tab
        let tickers = this.state.addedTickers;
        if (tickers.indexOf(data) === 0) {
            tickers.shift();
            this.showAll();
            console.log('zero');
        } else {
            tickers.splice(tickers.indexOf(data));
            this.showAll();
        }
    };

    savedTickerFilter = (f) => {
        this.setState({ searchedTicker: f.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        //Trimming searched input to all lowercase and filtering displayed post within return based on search
        let loaded = this.state.loaded,
            searchedTicker = this.state.searchedTicker.trim().toLowerCase();
        if (searchedTicker.length > 0) {
            loaded = loaded.filter(function(i) {
                return i.text.toLowerCase().match(searchedTicker);
            });
        }

        //Copying loaded state and attempting to added individual numbers of tweets to each tab
        let copyOfLoaded = [ ...this.state.loaded ];

        let filterCopy = copyOfLoaded.filter(function(i) {
            return i.text.toLowerCase().match(searchedTicker);
        });
        let numOfTweets = filterCopy.length;

        return (
            <div className="main" style={{ marginTop: 40 + 'px' }}>
                <h4>Search a stock symbol below to find relevant tweets from Stocktwitz.</h4>
                <h4>You may then press Add to Favorites to create a saved tab for later reference.</h4>
                <div className="main__inner">
                    <TextField
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.searchedTicker}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        placeholder="Search Ticker..."
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        label="Search"
                        variant="outlined"
                    />
                    <Button onClick={this.addTicker} variant="contained" color="primary">
                        Add to favorites <StarIcon style={{ marginLeft: 10 + 'px' }} />
                    </Button>
                </div>
                {/* This will be the Filter Tabs component and that will import the list thats below the Paper component below */}{' '}
                <Paper square>
                    <Tabs indicatorColor="primary" textColor="primary" onChange={this.handleTabChange}>
                        <Tab label={<div className="tabs-label">All ({loaded.length})</div>} onClick={this.showAll} />
                        {//Mapping through tabs that are added in TwitterBot component and passed down as props to this component
                        this.state.addedTickers.map((i) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="tab-container">
                                    <Tab
                                        label={
                                            <div className="tabs-label">
                                                {i}
                                                ({numOfTweets})
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                        key={i}
                                        onClick={(e) => this.handleTabState(e, i)}
                                    />
                                    <CloseIcon value={i} onClick={(e) => this.removeTicker(e, i)} />
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </Tabs>
                </Paper>
                <List className="tweets">
                    {loaded.map(function(i) {
                        return (
                            <ListItem key={i.id}>
                                {' '}
                                <TwitterIcon style={{ marginRight: 10 + 'px', color: '#1da1f2' }} />
                                <Highlighter
                                    highlightClassName="YourHighlightClass"
                                    searchWords={[ searchedTicker ]}
                                    autoEscape={true}
                                    textToHighlight={i.text}
                                />,
                            </ListItem>
                        );
                    })}
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TwitterBot;
```

Above is the entire component that holds all necessary logic.

I basically want {{numOfTweets}} within the tab-label to be static to each Tab thats mapped through once created. Right now it correctly will show how many items per tab there are while searching, and if clicked on current tab, but all tabs will react. I need them to stay static after search so if clicked on another tab, the past tab will still show how many tweets there were for that searched tab. Right now it's happening just because it's referencing the global loaded state, I just need  way to copy that and render each one individually. I hope I explained that clear enough. You can see what I mean on my **demo here**: https://5ec5b3cfc2858ad16d22bd3c--elastic-khorana-7c2b7c.netlify.app/

I understand I need to break out and componentize this more, but I know theres has to be an easy solution, somehow using a simple functional component to wrap the Tab component or simple just the number that will be displayed. (I'm using Material UI)

Thank you, anything helps, just need to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-leftpad-j0rgd

I have added an object instead of a string for Addedtickers so that the count can be tracked and remains constant throughout. You can further optimize this , if you want to search again within each individual tab, but you get the gist.
Please let me know if this works for you

Comment: Yes this worked perfect! Thank you so much, just needed to see it done to wrap my head around it. Truly appreciate it.